# HDMI not works once unplugged and pluged again

Tags: linux, nvidia, elementary-os, hdmi

Hello i am experiencing a very weird issue i checked other similar questions in the stack but it seems they are old and some how not working for me.

**PROBLEM**

When i attach external LED using HDMI in my laptop, i have to reboot my laptop while the HDMI cable is plugged, it shows the secondary desktop just perfectly as its supposed to but during usage just in case if i unplug the wire and plug it again the monitor does not shows any thing, but rebooting again solves the problem only if cable was attached plugged during boot process.

**OS & Hardware**

I am using the following configurations

```
Ubuntu Jammy
Dell Laptop (Core i5, 11th gen, 16Gb, Nvidia RTX)
```

The OS detail info is following

```
PRETTY_NAME="elementary OS 7 Early Access"
NAME="elementary OS"
VERSION_ID="7"
VERSION="7 Early Access"
VERSION_CODENAME=next
ID=elementary
ID_LIKE=ubuntu
HOME_URL="https://elementary.io/"
DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://elementary.io/docs/learning-the-basics"
SUPPORT_URL="https://elementary.io/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://github.com/elementary/os/issues/new"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://elementary.io/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
```

Is it possible to trigger the HDMI change event using terminal manually to let OS know about the latest event or any shell script or another helpful command, or any service which is started at boot time for HDMI which i can trigger manually to solve my problem.

Comment: obviously i mean a secondary display e,g LED, monitor is a old term so i didn't used this word

Comment: like this one https://www.symbios.pk/image/cache/data/i/IMG_352265_1413272346-500x500.jpg

Comment: the LED Backlight LCD Monitor then